# Haskell : display/get list of all user defined functions

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci, winghci

Is there a command in Haskell which displays (or get as a list of) all the user defined functions which have been loaded/defined in the GHCi? Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To see bindings you've made at the ghci prompt (e.g. with `let` or `<-`), try `:show bindings`.

If you've loaded some modules, you can use `:show modules` to get the names of loaded modules and then `:browse ModuleName` to list everything in scope from that module.

Comment: Hi, I tried that but it did not work for me. I am using WinGHCi and I loaded the functions via the ':load' function as outlined in the post [Haskell : loading ALL files in current directory path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268692/haskell-loading-all-files-in-current-directory-path). However when I try ':show bindings' it just says 'it :: Int = 7' because I invoked 'addNumber2 3 4' last. Thanks

Comment: I edited in instructions for what you do if there are modules.

Comment: Hi, :browse requires knowledge of which module has been loaded. Is there a way of doing this without requiring knowledge of which modules have been loaded? (see also comment below). Thanks.

Comment: I don't think so, unless you can parse the output of `:show modules`.

Answer (score 10):

When in ghci, use `:browse` or just `:bro` after loading the file. You may also browse unloaded modules via `:browse Foo.Bar.Baz`.

Comment: `:br` now resolves to `:break`, for browsing, you need `:bro`.

Comment: `:dawg` should be a ghci synonym for `:bro`

Comment: Hi I tried this, but in WinGHCi ':browse' does nothing! I loaded the files as outlined in the post [Haskell : loading ALL files in current directory path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268692/haskell-loading-all-files-in-current-directory-path)

Comment: Did you try `:browse ModuleName`?

Comment: Ah I didnt realise that you have to specify the module name. But suppose I have scripts to load different modules. Then is there a way to see all the functions which have been loaded from the various modules, without requiring knowledge of which modules have been loaded? Thanks

Comment: @artella In ghci, `:browse` with no arguments shows the bindings defined in the currently loaded module(s). Perhaps you should upgrade from hugs. =)