# Is there a way to list names of loaded functions in GHCi?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I have a haskell file my.hs in a directory. In that directory I run GHCi. At the prompt I type

```
:load my.hs
```

Is there some command in GHCi that will list the names of all the functions loaded from the file? I didn't find it in the help which is displayed by :? in GHCi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this question was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272094/haskell-display-get-list-of-all-user-defined-functions)

The command I was looking for was

```
:browse Main
```