# Haskell : unload module in WinGHCi

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci, winghci

I loaded two modules (NecessaryModule1.hs and NecessaryModule2.hs as outlinked in [Haskell : loading ALL files in current directory path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268692/haskell-loading-all-files-in-current-directory-path)). Now I want to unload NecessaryModule2.hs. I found an 'unload' function in [System.Plugins.Load](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/plugins/1.5.1.4/doc/html/System-Plugins-Load.html) however but it did not work in WinGHCi. The error message I got was :

```
>unload NecessaryModule2

<interactive>:1:1: Not in scope: `unload'

<interactive>:1:8:
    Not in scope: data constructor `NecessaryModule2'
```

I tried

```
import System.Plugins.Load
```

but that did not work. Is there a way to unload modules in the manner described above?

### ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[RESPONSE TO Riccardo]

Hi Riccardo, I tried your suggestion but I could not get it to work in WinGHCi. I had a file NecessaryModule1.hs as follows :

```
module NecessaryModule1 where

addNumber1 :: Int -> Int -> Int
addNumber1 a b = a + b
```

I went to the location of the file via the ':cd' command, and then did :

```
> :module +NecessaryModule1

<no location info>:
    Could not find module `NecessaryModule1':
      it is not a module in the current program, or in any known package.
```

Is this correct? Thanks [EDIT : see below for correction]

### ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[CORRECTION TO ABOVE]

Just to explain why the above is incorrect (as explained by Riccardo), what needs to be done is the following :

If we have a file NecessaryModule1.hs as follows :

```
--NecessaryModule1.hs
module NecessaryModule1 where

addNumber1 :: Int -> Int -> Int
addNumber1 a b = a + b
```

then we do :

```
> :load NecessaryModule1
[1 of 1] Compiling NecessaryModule1 ( NecessaryModule1.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: NecessaryModule1.
> addNumber1 4 5
9
> :module -NecessaryModule1
> addNumber1 4 5

<interactive>:1:1: Not in scope: `addNumber1'
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Installed modules**

You have to use ghci's commands in order to load (`:module +My.Module`) and unload (`:module -My.Module`) installed modules. You can also use `:m` instead of `:module` in order to write less, like this:

```
Prelude> :m +Data.List
Prelude Data.List> sort [3,1,2]
[1,2,3]
Prelude Data.List> :m -Data.List
Prelude> sort [3,1,2]

<interactive>:1:1: Not in scope: `sort'
```

Remember that the ghci prompt always reminds you the module currently imported: you can have a look at that in  order to know what to unload with  `:m -Module.To.Unload`.

**Specific files**

If the module you're trying to load isn't installed in the system (e.g. you wrote the source and simply saved the file somewhere), you need to use a different command, `:load filename.hs`. A quicker way is to pass the path to the file directly as a command-line argument to `ghci`, e.g `ghci filename.hs`. If you run `winghci` and you associated it to the `.hs` extension, simply double-click the file.

In both cases you will get a ghci prompt with the specified module correctly loaded AND imported in scope (provided you don't have get compilation errors instead). As before, you can now use `:m [+/-] My.Module` to load and unload modules, but please note that this is different from `:load` because `:module` assumes you already `:load`ed what you're trying  to get in/out of scope.

E.g., if you have `test.hs`

```
module MyModule where
import Data.List

f x = sort x
```

you may load it by double-clicking it (on windows with winghci), by typing `ghci test.hs` in a console, or by loading `ghci` and typing `:load test.hs` (beware of relative/absolute paths).

Another useful ghci command is `:reload`, which will recompile the module you loaded before. Use it when you change the source file and you want to quickly update the module loaded in ghci.

```
Prelude> :load test.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling MyModule         ( test.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: MyModule.
*MyModule> let xs = [1,2,3] in sort xs == f xs
True
*MyModule> :reload
Ok, modules loaded: MyModule.
```

`:help` will give you a complete list of all available commands.

Comment: Hi Riccardo, I tried your suggestion but had some problems. I have posted above since there is too little space here. Thanks

Comment: Hi Riccardo, thanks a lot for your well explained answer. I really appreciate you spending the time to write all that out. Thank you.

Comment: `:m -Data.List` works, but it doesn't work with the Prelude. Any way to unload the Prelude?